# Can not publish project into file system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, publish

I try to publish my project to file system as always. There are my publish settings:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>e:\vspublish\audit</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But publish failed with this error: Azure App Service Activity: Connecting to e:\vspublish\audit...

[image]

I dont want to use Azure App Service, i just want to publish project to file system.

Comment: Which do you use visual studio version?

Comment: 2k15 version of studio

Comment: I still can not figure out the problem. To solve this i just created another empty solution and copied all files from last project. New solution can be published as always.

Comment: I have notice that if I do a rebuild of my project, there's a 50% chance that the publish will work. No clue why.  Also, the last time it failed several times in a row so I gave up and worked on something else.  An hour later tried again with no other changes and it worked just fine.  IIS holding on to a file maybe? Who knows. I'm going to try moving to VS2017.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens when i try to update `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package using Nuget Manager to last stable version (its 2.6.1 atm):
[image: Update Microsoft.Net.Compilers package]

If i do not do an upgrade, the publication is successful:
[image: the publication is successful]

Why is this happening and where to configure this Assembly? In the settings of the project, no integration or connection to Azure at all.

Comment: Now i use VS 2k17 and there is no problem with latest version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Comment: Today, August 14th, Year 2018... 2.8 and 2.8.1 both fail. 2.4.0 succeeds.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this information can help someone. I had the same issue as reported here - and would like to share it here too or to confirm the solution to the problem.

Publishing did not work (file system, web or any other), everything builds but the resulting message was:

```
11>Connecting to C:\MY_LOCATION...
11>
========== Build: 10 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

No additional information was provided. Changing the VS build output settings did not lead to any more information than I already had. 
Then I stumbled upon this post, reverted to `Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.6.0"` did not help. Same result.

Comparing the Nuget packages with the branch that worked, turned out that publishing work fine with:

I have to point out that loading and publishing the same project (same settings) work fine with Visual Studio 2017.

After reverting to 2.4.0 version, things work fine in my case too.

Additional info:

- Visual Studio 2015
- C# ASP MVC Project

Hope this helps!

Happy coding

Comment: thanks for the solution.. I had the exact same problem. Downgrading NET Framework from 4.6.1 to 4.5, made my VS2015 unable to publish the website (although publishing in VS2017 worked fine).
But when I downgraded the version of NET Compilers, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Select Custom Option. Enter a Profile name. Click OK. This should then display different publish settings as required, ie; File System etc.

Comment: I only did this. Publishing (File System) to a completely different location actually worked. Why it worked is the big question

Answer (score 0):

you need go to folder of project , find .vs folder (you need turn on hidden file in folder option) and delete all file in this ,then build project . good luck

Answer (score 0):

My project was installed with `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and it wasn't required. I removed it using Nuget Package Manager. It now works no problem.